# iphone simulator will not open in Titanium, but no error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, titanium, ios-simulator

I am attempting to use titanium for the first time, and am new to development.  When I try to run the kitchen sink project through the iphone simulator, it seems that it successfully builds the project, but immediately closes it.  There are no error messages, but the console reads:

```
[INFO] :   Deploy type: development
[INFO] :   Building for target: simulator
[INFO] :   Building using iOS SDK: 6.1
[INFO] :   Building for iOS iPhone Simulator: 6.1
[INFO] :   Building for device family: iphone
[INFO] :   Minimum iOS version: 5.0
[INFO] :   Debugging disabled
[INFO] :   Profiler disabled
[INFO] :   Initiating prepare phase
[INFO] :   Copying custom Info.plist from project directory
[INFO] :   Forcing rebuild: custom Info.plist CFBundleIdentifier not equal to tiapp.xml <id>
[INFO] :   Found Titanium module id=facebook version=latest platform=iphone deploy-type=development
[INFO] :   Detected third-party native iOS module: facebook version 3.1.1
[INFO] :   Cleaning old build directory
[INFO] :   Performing full rebuild
[INFO] :   Copying Xcode iOS files
[INFO] :   Creating Xcode project directory: /Users/robertjackel/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/Kitchen Sink/build/iphone/KitchenSink.xcodeproj
[INFO] :   Writing Xcode project data file: Titanium.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
[INFO] :   Writing Xcode project configuration: project.xcconfig
[INFO] :   Writing Xcode module configuration: module.xcconfig
[INFO] :   Creating symlinks for simulator build
[INFO] :   Injecting native libraries into Xcode project file
[INFO] :   Forcing rebuild: ApplicationDefaults.m has changed since last build
[INFO] :   Writing properties to ApplicationDefaults.m
[INFO] :   Copying module resources
[INFO] :   No CommonJS modules to copy
[INFO] :   Loading and parsing JSS files
[INFO] :   Compiling localization files
[INFO] :   Invoking xcodebuild
[INFO] :   Finished building the application in 39s 143ms
[INFO] :   Running application in iOS Simulator
[INFO] :   Launching application in iOS Simulator
[INFO] :   Focusing the iOS Simulator
[INFO] :   Application has exited from iOS Simulator
[INFO] :   Project built successfully in 40s 320ms
```

The same is true with the ipad simulator.  I have installed the newest versions of titanium and xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to go into the simulator though Xcode. Open Xcode and  go to Xcode on your top bar then open developer tools then IOS Simulator.

Then once the simulator opens goto IOS Simulator on the top bar and click Reset content and settings...

Let me know if that works ?:)

Comment: I tried this, and got the exact same result.  I'm tempted to uninstall both xcode and titanium.